# Регулярное выражение с исключением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, posix, like, mysql

Доброго времени суток! Нужна помощь в написании регулярного выражения. В базе есть таблица chars с полями `id`, `title`, `val`, в которой хранятся значения val, например:

1. |Хром матовый|Золото|
2. |Антик|Хром|
3. Квадратный
4. Круглый

(Символ "|" не означает, что я пытался таблицу рисовать, этот символ относится к строке, которая хранится в поле `val`.)

Проблема в следующем: мне необходимо по запросу получить `title`, часть условия в запросе первоначально была такая:

```
WHERE val LIKE '%$value%'
```

Но в таком случае, если `$value='Хром'`, то подходят записи с `val` равном как `|Антик|Хром|` (что правильно), так и `|Хром матовый|Золото|` (что неправильно).
Заменил `LIKE` на `RLIKE`, написал такое выражение:

```
$rlike='('.$value.'[^[:space:]])';
WHERE val RLIKE '$rlike'
```

Получилось, что при `$value='Хром'` всё идеально, т.к. поля с таким значением содержат несколько так сказать наборов переменных (разделены "|"), но когда, например, `$value='Круглый'`, он ничего не находит. (

Помогите написать правильную регулярку!

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```
where '|'+val+'|' rlike '|$value|'
```

А можете рассказать, зачем вам такая структура данных, с которой вы работать не можете/не умеете?

**Обновление**

Все просто. Ваша структура находится не в первой нормальной форме. И недостатки проектирования вы пытаетесь оправдать каким-то регулярками. Очевидно правильный вариант - декомпозиция, после которой написать запрос не составит никакого труда. И вопрос бы вы не задавали, разумеется.

Да, естественно код в ответе работать не будет, т.к. формат регулярных выражений для mysql свой. Это был псевдокод.

Вот вам [фидл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05a72/26) с работающим запросом.

```
where CONCAT('|',val,'|') rlike '.*[[.vertical-line.]]$value[[.vertical-line.]].*';
```

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что я не могу или не умею с такой структурой данных работать? Возникла ситуация, когда стандартный подход, применяемый для большинства других рядовых ситуаций, не подходит. Не было всё до конца продумано.
Кстати, Ваш метод не работает. Вы уверены, что поняли суть проблемы?

Comment: Обновил ответ